# Obtener todos los números de un string, incluyendo el signo negativo, y devolverlos como array

Tags: c#, .net, regex

**Obtjetivo**

Estoy intentando obtener todos los números del siguiente texto:

> ```
> (2/3x^2/3) * (1/4X^-1/2)
> ```

**Intento**

Estoy haciendo un split del texto usando la expresión regular:

```
@"\D+"
```

para que me elimine todos los caracteres que no son numéricos. El problema es que no me deja el signo `-` del número negativo (lo elimina junto al resto).

**Código**

Este es el código que intenté, pasando el texto `(2/3x^2/3) * (1/4X^-1/2)`

```
        char separador = '*';
        string[] partes = operacion.Split(separador);

        string[] digitos = Regex.Split(partes[0], @"\D+");
        constan1 = Convert.ToInt32(digitos[0]);
        constan11 = Convert.ToInt32(digitos[1]);
        exponen1 = Convert.ToInt32(digitos[2]);
        exponen11 = Convert.ToInt32(digitos[3]);
```

---

**Pregunta**

¿Cómo puedo

- Obtener cada uno de los números.
- Que sean obtenidos como un array.
- Que pueda referenciarlos individualmente (para asignarlos en una variable).

Comment: agregare una imagen de lo que estoy haciendo

Comment: Siempre van a ser entradas iguales? (`(1/2x^1/2) / (2/3x^2/3)`)  mismas operaciones con distintos numeros?

Comment: Esa es la entrada original pero hay que derivarlas y después hacer lo demás con cada resultado de cada una, ya edite la pregunta y puse el resultado que necesito que se opere en el método. Y si seria la misma entrada pero diferentes numeros

Comment: Estoy trabajando en una calculadora de derivadas, y ahorita el objetivo es de derivada de la división con fracciones y todo esta bien el único problema que tengo es que me elimina el signo `-` y el resultado no sale correcto porque solo quedan números positivos. Y cuando hago la suma de fracciones el signo `-`no lo toma en cuenta porque ha sido eliminado con el regex

Comment: Exacto! conservando el signo `-` y que el signo `^` sea eliminado

Comment: @Mariano acabo de actualizar mi pregunta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La siguiente expresión coincide con un número, opcionalmente con decimales, conservando el signo negativo (si lo hubiese):

```
 (?:- *)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

Luego, para obtener todas las coincidencias, recorremos la colección devuelta por [Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Código**

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

```cs
string patron = @"(?:- *)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?";
string operacion = "(2/3x^2/3) * (1/4X^-1/2)";
Regex regex = new Regex(patron);

foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(operacion))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Número: {0}", m.Value);
}
```

**Resultado**

```
Número: 2
Número: 3
Número: 2
Número: 3
Número: 1
Número: 4
Número: -1
Número: 2
```

**Demo**

http://ideone.com/E1c9rA

---

**¿Cómo referenciar un item específico?**

Directamente usando el índice de [MatchCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx). Ejemplo `mc[0].Value`.

```cs
string patron = @"(?:- *)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?";
string operacion = "(2/3x^2/3) * (1/4X^-1/2)";
Regex regex = new Regex(patron);

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(operacion);

Console.WriteLine("Cantidad: {0}\nNúmero 3: {1}\nNúmero 5: {2}", 
                  matches.Count, 
                  matches[2].Value, 
                  matches[4].Value
                 );
```

---

**¿O cómo convertir todos los resultados en array?**

Haciendo una conversión de tipo y llevando a array.

```cs
string patron = @"(?:- *)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?";
string operacion = "(2/3x^2/3) * (1/4X^-1/2)";
Regex regex = new Regex(patron);

string[] resultados = regex.Matches(operacion)
                           .OfType<Match>()
                           .Select(m => m.Value)
                           .ToArray();
```

```cs
//Imprimimos algunos
Console.WriteLine("Número 1: {0}\nNúmero 2: {1}", 
                  resultados[0],
                  resultados[1]
                 );
```

Comment: Se puede implementar con un array ya que siento que es mas facil, o como hago en un foreach para que cada uno de los datos me los guarde en una variable para poder despues operar?

Comment: El ultimo método me ha funcionado muchísimas gracias viejo!!

Comment: Si era justo lo que buscaba!!